# Looking for new placement on poor performing ads

Tags: seo, google-adsense, advertising

I don't know if this is an acceptable question in this forum.  But, I'm seeking advice on better ad placement for a site.

I have a site that's averaging 2000 unique visitors a day right now.  It's not getting a good CTR at all.

You can see the add placement here [Hollywoodnose.com](http://hollywoodnose.com/CameronDiazNoseJob).

I'd put a screenshot but you need higher rep. points.

As you can see I have the 3 main ads.

I've tried a bunch of layouts.  The right rectangle seems a little shoved in the users face.  But, I've put it at the bottom too with a comparable CTR.

Any suggestions on how to improve the ad placement?  Thank you.